# How do I convert constraints's toItem or Item from viewA to viewB? I am getting this error: Unknown layout attribute

Tags: swift

As title, I have the viewParent which has viewA,
but viewA will be replaced by viewB within method `awakeAfter`.

I wanna convert all of constraints

> from viewParent <-> viewA,
>
> to viewParent <-> viewB.

Thanks a lots.

Here is my code:

```
private func convertConstraints(from: UIView, to: UIView){
        from.constraints.forEach { (constraint: NSLayoutConstraint) in
            let isFirst = (constraint.firstItem as? UIView) == from
            let isSecond = (constraint.secondItem as? UIView) == from

            let first: Any = (isFirst) ? to : constraint.firstItem as Any
            let second: Any? = (isSecond) ? to : constraint.secondItem as? Any

            let new = NSLayoutConstraint(item: first,
                               attribute: constraint.firstAttribute,
                               relatedBy: constraint.relation,
                               toItem: second,
                               attribute: constraint.secondAttribute,
                               multiplier: constraint.multiplier,
                               constant: constraint.constant)
            new.priority = constraint.priority
            new.identifier = constraint.identifier
            new.shouldBeArchived = constraint.shouldBeArchived
            new.isActive = constraint.isActive
        }
    }
```

And console log is below:

```
2019-03-27 15:36:33.740004+0800 Cale[86571:50392102] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'NSLayoutConstraint for <Cale.AirportButton: 0x7f9eb454d990; baseClass = UIButton; frame = (0 129; 120 120); autoresize = RM+BM; layer = <CALayer: 0x600003936460>>: Unknown layout attribute'
*** First throw call stack:
(
    0   CoreFoundation                      0x000000010bf501bb __exceptionPreprocess + 331
    1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x000000010b4ee735 objc_exception_throw + 48
    2   CoreFoundation                      0x000000010bf50015 +[NSException raise:format:] + 197
    3   Foundation                          0x000000010a16cf61 ResolveConstraintArguments + 372
    4   Foundation                          0x000000010a16d2cb +[NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:attribute:relatedBy:toItem:attribute:multiplier:constant:] + 80
.
.
.
```

Comment: Why don't you just remove the constraints and add them to the second view?
make sure to add the constraints to the needed view after adding the view

Comment: Instead of replacing the view. Create a container remove and add the required views from it.

Comment: Because both of viewA which is initialized from code and viewB is loaded from Nib are the same class. And yes, I can remove the constraints but I also need add same them to the second view like the method doing.

Comment: I'm based on following link and trying to refactor it. [Creating custom UI components in iOS with Swift](https://medium.com/@Kirillzzy/create-a-custom-button-for-ios-e81026bd6148)

Answer (score 1):

I fixed it,... thanks a lot.

I modified code from:

```
let second: Any? = (isSecond) ? to : constraint.secondItem as? Any
```

to:

```
let second: Any? = (isSecond) ? to : constraint.secondItem
```

Comment: type Optional<Any?>  v.s. Any?